# Screen Capture software that can record at 60fps or more

Tags: osx, screen-recording

I am desperately looking for professional screen capture software that can record at 60 fps (or thereabouts), and includes all other professional specs i.e. annotations, V.O recording, video editing etc. I am currently using Camtasia 2 for mac, which functions very well regarding the above mentioned specs, but my animated video recordings are playing back "jerky." I am convinced that this is because Camtasia 2 is limited to screen capture of no more than 30 fps. This has been a lingering problem and I am anxious to solve it! Help!

Comment: Interesting, there is no such limitation on Camtasia for Windows. (https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/can_camtasia_record_higher_than_30_fps ; http://i.stack.imgur.com/9klBa.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Screenflick](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26035/screenflick):

- Nonfree
- Mac OS X
- up to 60 FPS

[image]

Comment: Thanks Franck! Frame rate seems great, but lacks the annotation/editing power I need to complete my screencasts! Looks like I'll stick with a slightly "jumpy" Camtasia 2 for now....thanks anyway!

Comment: @Mr.Ret Sorry I had missed that requirements: how about post processing with some video editing software?